# Remove UIButton Programmatically in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, ios9

I have added multiple buttons programmatically in my project. I use NSTimer in my viewDidLoad method to call the function to add more buttons every 5 seconds. My problem is I want to clear the buttons from the view which was previously created as new buttons are getting created on top of the old ones.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("subtractTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func subtractTime() {
   let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect) as UIButton
   //button.removeFromSuperview
   for var i = 0; i < size; i++ {
        for var j = 0; j < size; j++ {
          button.frame = CGRectMake(self.x, self.y, BoxWidthHeight, BoxWidthHeight)
          button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
          button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
          button.tag = tagcounter
          self.view.addSubview(button)
        }
    }
}
```

I have read that `button.removeFromSuperview` should do the work, but i dont get all the buttons removed by it and same remains on the screen.

Comment: where is your code for removing the buttons?

Comment: What you had written for removing the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

```
for locView in self.view.subviews {
    if locView.isKindOfClass(UIButton) {
        locView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @harshal if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this,

```
superview.subviews.forEach ({
    if $0 is UIButton {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }
})
```